# Creating multiple measures at once when you have many columns (Power Pivot)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have an excel file with 400 columns, containing - almost all of them - numerical values. I need to turn them into measures using Power Pivot (i need measures so to be able to use the Switch formula in PowerBI). Once I've created them, I am supposed to upload the spreadsheet again in PowerBI desktop.

The excel table is something like:

```
City  | Numerical1 | Numerical2| ... | Numerical400
_________________________________________________
Milan | 100        |     2     |     |    1
Rome  | 200        |     3     |     |    3
Naples| 300        |     4     |     |    9
```

The measure formula is simply:

```
Numerical1 measure = CALCULATE(SUM([COLUMN NAME]))
```

I know there is not an easy solution, but what is in your opinion the easiest way to create so many measures?

Comment: unpivot your table.

Comment: Are you thinking to a solution like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFd2hjkKz_Q&list=PLREfg6vaHQL81lHyhzqbixk8i5fQidwmW&index=3&t=1s It works only for categorical values. Otherwise I don't get why you say so